# How to create something similar to the `Edit` mode of an image in `Google Photos` in my Android app?

Tags: android

I want to create something similar to how the screen looks like in the `Edit-mode` of a photo in `Google Photos`, especially the screen where we can put the different filters, as shown below:

[image: Google Photos Edit Mode]

Now, the top part can be done using a simple `ImageView`. The bottom part can also be made by just using a `SeekBar`. But how do I create the middle part, that is the part, where all the filters are shown that can be slided left or right, and selected accordingly as shown above. Is there something in Android which does something like that, or do I need to create the entire thing from scratch?

Comment: use viewpager for this

Comment: But doesn't viewpager mean it takes up the entire screen? I just want it to take up just a small strip of place in the screen, swiping on which, only that strip would shift left/right, not the entire screen. How do I do that?

Comment: check this link https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: also check this site https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter it was really helpful for me, read it completely, your concern i guess is in this section `Tabbed Interface with Pager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `ViewPager`, you can use a `HorizontalScrollView` with `ImageView`s inside it. I think although this is not the *best* way to do this, this is certainly the most straightforward.

Here's roughly what you gotta do: (attributes are omitted for brevity, and laziness)

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
        <ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Easy, right? You can adjust the attributes however you want and BOOM! You did it!